# Linux ELF FILE SECTIONS NAME

Tags: linux, elf

I have a c program which get information from an ELF file.My question is : all section names have to start with dot(for example .sffa) ? It is a must or it is rather only for system files?

Comment: i don't know what you mean by that comment. my question is having an elf file i get the section names and i was wondering about the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section names beginning with a dot are [reserved for system stuff](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf#page=21) but other sections names can be used:

> **Section names with a dot prefix are reserved for the system**,
>   although applications may use these sections
>   if their existing meanings are satisfactory.  **Applications may use
>   names without the prefix** to avoid conflicts with system sections. The
>   object file format lets one define sections not in the list above. 
>   An object file may have more than one section with the same name.

Comment: so there is a chance that  some section names in an elf file to not start with a dot?